# Unreachable robots.txt error

Tags: google, robots.txt

I am getting *Unreachable robots.txt error* whenever I use fetch as Google. I know, on this site there is other queations related my issue.

But I also use Google Page Speed test, site is working correctly than getting 91/100 score.
how can I fix it?

Comment: Presumably your robots.txt is returned OK if requested from the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your *robots.txt* bear any empty `Disallow` like below:

```
 User-agent: *
 Disallow:
 Disallow: /cgi-bin/ 

 Sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml
```

It should be updated to:

```
 User-agent: * 
 Disallow: /cgi-bin/ 

 Sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: An empty `Disallow` field should simply be ignored by the Google bot (as invalid), it certainly shouldn't result in an "Unreachable" error!? (You should also have a blank line before the `Sitemap` field, in order to separate it from the preceding group.)

Comment: my problem has solved.

Comment: @w3d: Googlebot considers an empty `Disallow:` as invalid?! From the robots.txt specification perspective, it’s a perfectly valid line with the meaning "allow everything".

Comment: @unor: Well spotted - you're right, it's not invalid and Google doesn't state this. However, Google does [formally define the path value](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) as `pathvalue = "/" path` (which implies it cannot be empty) and later states that "When no path is specified, the directive is ignored" (which will have the same result as _allowing_). I would add, however, that 99% of the time, an empty `Disallow` field is in error (or simply unnecessary).